# WP Login Button for current domain

Tags: php, wp-admin

I want to make a link that goes to wp-login.php for whatever domain I'm at now. Something like:

```
<a href="http://<script>document.write(document.domain);</script>/wp-login.php">Login</a>
```

But I don't know how to write / format that properly.

Comment: What is the context in which this needs to work?

Comment: it's in a php script

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php wp_loginout(); ?>
```

Or

```
<a href="http://<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-login.php">Login</a>
```

What am I missing?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Answer (score 0):

If it is for the same domain something like this would also suffice:

`<a href="/wp-login.php">Login</a>`

But if you have the Wordpress api available the wp_loginout() function is the best available option.